# By pressing the enter button in the .js or .css file in the vs code the cursor again going to the previous line

Tags: visual-studio-code

By pressing the enter button in the .js or .css file in the vs code the cursor again going to the previous line.

is there any solution? Iam posting the video link below.

https://youtu.be/p1Tpw8GIJnU

Comment: Is it happening only in .js or .CSS file?

Comment: Have you tried disabling all extensions? Looks like one of them is doing things wrong.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.